# my inverted index did not get the right output

Tags: java, inverted-index

right now I'm working on inverted index that get a file in `xml` format then using `Jsoup` parser to get the text between `<description>` tag 
the split the text into word and see whether this word in the `index hash map` or not

if `No` then add this word as a key and the value is the path for the file that the word in

if `yes` (i.e. the word in the hash map) then just add file path for this word

Here some part of my code that I have problem in it

```
Map<String, List<String>> index = new HashMap<>();
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(xmlAsText.toString());
           Elements descriptions = doc.getElementsByTag("DESCRIPTION");

           if(descriptions.size() > 0)
                                    {
                line= descriptions.get(0).text();
                    for (String _word :  line.split("\\W+")) 
                    {

                      String word = _word.toLowerCase();
                      List<String> idx = index.get(word);
                            if (idx == null)//the word not in the index 
                            {
                                idx = new LinkedList<>();
                                idx.add(file.getParent() + "\\" + file.getName());
                                index.put(word, idx);
                               // System.out.println(file.getName()+"    "+word);
                            }
                            idx.add(file.getParent() + "\\" + file.getName());

                    }
         }
```

and when I ran my code I got output

Here a screen shoot 
[sample from the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mcApQ.png)

**BUT**
there are some files without any word (key)
and some of words did not exist in the index 
is there any error in my code?? or did I miss something !!

Comment: What did you find when you ran your code in the debugger?

Comment: @takendarkk the same output appear

Comment: Could you define what your input and expected output is. The problem is a bit unclear to me. Nevertheless I see 2 points of confusion already: (1) when the key is not yet in the index, you add the file path, but afterwards (outside the if) you additionally add the same file path, is this expected behaviour? (2) You only use the first description in the HTML file (`descriptions.get(0)`), are you certain there aren't more?

Comment: @DJanssens this code in a method that have a file as input and return a hashMap of all the word in the file and the file path

Comment: and add the file path in the first place if the word does not exist it will add the word and the path but if it exist then it will use the add file that is outside the if condition

Comment: the last question you asked about description tag the file contains many tags like <title> <docID> but I want to index just what is inside <description>

Comment: I agree and understand, but is there just a single <description> tag inside the file? I believe there is an issue though, you seem to add the path when initially the index doesn't exist, but then when the if ended you also add it a second time. I believe you need to use an else statement there to prevent this.

Comment: yes there is just one <description> tag ,,ok I get what are you taking about I will try to fix it :) thanx

Comment: @DJanssens last question can I add a new Arraylist to an existing key(word)?

Comment: Why do you need to add a new `Arraylist` to an existing key, shouldn't you just append the new file path to the retrieved list associated to that key? :)

Comment: assume that another file contains the same word that you already stored it in the map then this word will add the new file for this word for example `Tree [doc1,doc2,doc3]`

Comment: @DJanssens I google it and I found this `index.get(word).add(file.getParent() + "\\" + file.getName());`

Comment: thanx for  your time and question and notes :)

Comment: No problem, I hope it works now ;)

Comment: kind of :P but there is some word not in the index I don't know why but I will try again :)